# Sorting 1,000,000 Objects (not by Key) - Java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, abstract-data-type

I have c.1,000,000 objects that need to be stored in some form of data structure. They must be unique by a key (ID) - but sorted according to their date. I'm therefore trying to think of a best way of storing them in some form of data structure. 
Performance (in terms of time taken to execute) it the primary goal, and then memory usage. My idea was to put the objects into a Tree, so they may be sorted according to their date as they enter the data structure, and I can then return them in order. However - I think this is going to be horrendously slow to find a single object based on it's ID. One thought that did occur to me was to have a secondary structure which linked ID's to dates so I can reduce the time taken to find the single object, or just store everything by this ID anyway (perhaps in a HashTable) and then just sort through all 1,000,000 objects when I want to return them (although this seems to take a very long time).

### Key Points:

Objects may be added afterwards so the c.1,000,000 objects ARE NOT fixed. They WILL NOT be updated or removed.
I MAY NOT use Java's built in Comparator.
I am optimising for efficiency of returning the data - whether this be the complete set in order (by date), or a single object obtained from it's ID.

Comment: Have you tried `Comparator` to achieve your task...?

Comment: could you list the use cases for which youre optimizing? they might affect the choice of data structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if performance in your chief concern before memory usage, i'd go with 2 datastructures:

```
ArrayList<YourClass> instancesByDate;
```

and

```
HashMap<SomeId,YourClass> instancesById;
```

this gives you the fastest traversal by date and O(1) lookup (depending on hashCode() obviously).

Comment: I would go for a `SortedSet` with a custom `Comperator<T>` passed in on construction. This way you don't need to implement "insert at correct position" by hand.

Comment: @MartinThurau - good point. OP didnt specify if he gets all the data beforehand or he needs fast update. its also possible to extend LinkedHashMap and get O(1) lookup by ID and chronological iteration in a single structure, but that would be complex.

Comment: Sorry - I will update the question now to explain a few more things. @MartinThurau

Comment: ok, from reading the updated question my answer still stands - " I am optimising for efficiency of returning the data - whether this be the complete set in order (by date), or a single object obtained from it's ID" means an expensive insertion op is ok (and iteration over arraylist is faster than set/tree iteration). abd about implementing insertion "by habd" - the return value of Collections.binarySearch will give you the index you want to insert into, so nothing really to implement here.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a hashtable of ID => yourobject for the ID lookups, and a secondary hashtable of date (at some level of granularity) => `Vector<yourobject>`?  You could choose the 'granularity' of the date to ensure you've a moderate number of objects in each vector - and sort each by date.